# Some objects disappeared in the modeling tab after render

Tags: objects

After rendering to see how my model looked so far, most of the objects in my scene disappeared from the modeling tab (using 2.8), they aren't hidden, alt H doesn't bring them back and they are set to be visible in the organizer. They are visible in all tabs except for modeling.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are in an isolated view inside of the Modeling tab.
Go to `View` > `Local View` > `Toggle Local View` or press <kbd>Num /</kbd>.
(Blender 2.7: `View` > `View Global/Local`)

[image: Toggle Local View Menu Screenshot]

You know that you're in isolated mode / local view if it says **User Perspective (Local)** in the top left corner.

[image: User Perspective (Local) Screenshot]